# Posting dynamically created input to database mvc5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to post some strings(texts) to DB from a a dynamically created input.

Here is the code for generating that input. Im using another text box(id='newtypevalue') to enter values to that input. There is a delete button associated with inputs.

Here is the _AttributeCreate partial view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Atribute"))
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.AtributeCode)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.AtributeName)

  <div>
  <input type="text" id="newtypevalue" /></div>

  <div>
  <input type="button" value="Add Text" id="addtypevalue" /></div>  

  <div id="typevaluelist">
    // Generate inputs for existing items and in case of returning the view
    @foreach(var item in Model.typevalue)
    {
    <div class="typevalue">
        <input type="text" name="typevalue" value="@item" />
        <button type="button" class="delete">Delete</button>
    </div>
    }
   </div>

    <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" id="btn" class="btn btn-success"/>
    </div>

}

// Hidden template for adding new items (outside the form element)
<div id="new" style="display:none;">
  <div class="typevalue">
    <input type="text" name="typevalue" />
    <button type="button" class="delete">Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>

//scripts for adding and deleting items
$('#addtypevalue').click(function() {
   var clone = $('#new').clone().children('div'); // copy the template
   clone.find('input').val($('#newtypevalue').val()); // update text
   $('#typevaluelist').append(clone); // add it to the DOM
   $('#newtypevalue').val(''); // clear initial text box
});

$('#typevaluelist').on('click', '.delete', function() {
   $(this).closest('.typevalue').remove(); // remove it from the DOM
});
```

AttributeViewModel

```
public class AttributeViewModel
{
   public string AtributeCode { get; set; }

   public string AtributeName { get; set; }

   public IEnumerable<String> typevalue { get; set; }
}
```

In Attribute Controller

```
public ActionResult Save(AttributeViewModel avm)
    {
        var objContext = new KnittingdbContext();

        Atribute newAtt = new Atribute
        {
            AtributeCode=avm.AtributeCode,
            AtributeName=avm.AtributeName
        };

        objContext.Atributes.Add(newAtt);
        objContext.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("AtributeIndex", new { A = "New" });
    }
```

AttributeCode and Attribute name are saved to Attribute table whereas dynamically created inputs are saved to another table called AttributeDetail which has a FK relationship with Attribute table.

All these values should be saved to DB once i submit through the Submit button with id 'btn'. I am able to save relevant entries(AttributeCode and AttributeName) to Attribute table. But the difficulty is with saving dynamically created texts to AttributeDetail table. Im struggling with capturing those texts and posting them. All help appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your POST method has is `public ActionResult Save(AttributeViewModel model)` then `model.typevalue` contains all the values of your dynamically created textboxes. What is the current code you have for saving the data?

Comment: Thanks for replying.. :) Pls give me few mins to update my qusetion to reflect that.

Comment: Once you have saved `Attribute` you can then loop through each item in `avm.typevalue` and create a new `AttributeDetail` object and add them to your database (and call `.SaveChanges()` after the loop). But you have not indicated what properties `AttributeDetail` contains or how it relates to `Attribute` so unsure what properties you need to set

Comment: Ok thanks now i understand. I thought, for this i have to use jquery to capture those data. I'll try it in your way and tell you the result in few mins.

Comment: That worked.. Thanks you very much for helping me :)